# How to insert integers of an array of 0 to n^5-1 into an AVL tree?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

Given n distinct integers in the range 0, 1, ··· , n^5 − 1, design a worst-case linear-time algorithm to construct an AVL tree on these integers.

I think the idea is to shrink the problem basically meaning change the base from n^5 -1 to N and then inserting it into an AVL tree. But dont know how to do it though!

Comment: An AVL tree is just a self-balancing binary search tree. But, because you know all of the numbers ahead of time, you can add the numbers to the tree in [level order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search), which avoids the need for searching and re-balancing. You *do* have to compute the balance factors correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Balanced Binary Search Tree for numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766159/balanced-binary-search-tree-for-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

The "n^5" gives it away:  Sort the integers with radix sort, using *n* as the radix.  This will take *O(n)* time (5 passes) and *O(n)* space.  Then build a balanced binary tree.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort, and [Building Red-Black Tree from sorted array in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970804/building-red-black-tree-from-sorted-array-in-linear-time)